# Java Enum Returns Null

Tags: java, pointers, exception, enums, null

I am currently creating a plugin for Minecraft using the SpigotAPI. Reason I'm posting this here is because this I believe is a Java error. I am creating a duels plugin where inside my code it'll loop through an enum, and see if it's a specific type. The first time using it around it properly works, no problems. But when I try it for a second time without restarting my plugin/program/code it'll return the enum as null. Here is the code, is there a fix to this?

```
public DuelArenas[] getArenasWithType(DuelTypes type) {
    String suffix = "_NORMAL";
    List<DuelArenas> arenasAsList = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (type) {
        case NORMAL:
            suffix = "_NORMAL";
            break;
    }
    for (DuelArenas arena : duelArenaStatus.keySet()) {
        if (arena.toString().endsWith(suffix)) {
            arenasAsList.add(arena);
        }
    }
    DuelArenas[] arenas = new DuelArenas[arenasAsList.size()];
    return arenasAsList.toArray(arenas);
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at me.nick.acore.duels.DuelsAPI.getArenasWithType(DuelsAPI.java:97) ~[?:?]
```

And yes I've checked to see if the enum was null, and it was in fact null. Also line 97 is

```
if (arena.toString().endsWith(suffix)) {
```

And finally here is the DuelArena class

```
public enum DuelArenas {

ARENA_1_NORMAL, ARENA_2_NORMAL, ARENA_3_NORMAL, ARENA_4_NORMAL, ARENA_5_NORMAL,
ARENA_6_NORMAL, ARENA_7_NORMAL, ARENA_8_NORMAL, ARENA_9_NORMAL, ARENA_10_NORMAL,
ARENA_11_NORMAL, ARENA_12_NORMAL }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where and how `duelArenaStatus` is declared/modified ?

Comment: @alfasin Added to main post.

Comment: The enum is `DuelArenas` and you're trying to call `duelArenaStatus` that's not the same...

Comment: What is the 'duelArenaStatus' variable? If the duelArenaStatus is a HashMap, it could be that 'null' key has been inserted into it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you cannot directly convert your custom `DuelArenas` class to a string. However when you are comparing to see if a `.toString()` ends with `suffix`, I feel that something is also going wrong. You would only ever use `.toString` to convert things like numbers to strings, and if your are converting a number to a string there is no way it will end in `_NORMAL`.
So if you want me to troubleshoot further please post your `DuelArenas` class, but until then my best guess is that when you do `arena.toString` you are looking to pull some sort of value from that class that is stored in it, and to do this you would do `arena.variableInsideArenaName` and work with that.

**EDIT:**
After seeing the class scratch that, the error in going to be somewhere in this line `DuelArenas arena : duelArenaStatus.keySet()`

Comment: I have added the DuelArena class to the main post. So if I cant do .toString what should I do instead? As I want to see if the enum ends in _NORMAL.

Comment: please post what the variable duelArenaStatus is